# How are we to parse the phrase "A ship was a long time turning"?

Tags: grammar, phrases

The phrase **"it was a long time turning"** is found in the following sentence:

> Owing to the roughness of the sea, the steamer arrived late, when the
>   sun had already gone down, and **it was a long time turning** before it
>   tied up.

- Чехов, Антон Павлович. 2008. Anton Chekhov’s Short Stories, Second Edition (Norton Critical Edition). W. W. Norton & Company.

I would like to understand the grammar that enables its use. This sounds a bit strange to me. After all, we don't say such things as:

"I was hungry, and *I was a long time eating* before I got full."

Or do we?

We do have the common idiom *"it was a long time coming."* However, its idiomaticity is granted through wide usage. The topic sentence above is not so widely used. I therefore hesitate to consider it an idiom.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108613/discussion-on-question-by-touchstone-how-are-we-to-parse-the-phrase-a-ship-was).

Comment: *After all, we don't say such things as: "I was hungry, and I was a long time eating before I was full."* ... I do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel the question was answered by way of comment. However, that comment has been moved to chat so I think it's best to just copy that comment here. Thanks to the user -DW256- for his illuminating examples showing the construction having a settled history of usage. More pertinent to my question however is the parsing of the sentence. The user -Tinfoil Hat- supplied that information:

> *The ship was a long time turning.* --> *The ship was turning a long
>   time.* *Turn* is the verb, in its past progressive form (*was turning*). *A
>   long time* functions adverbially to modify that verb (and it's okay
>   that it's a noun phrase doing that).

[Compare adverbial nouns here](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-adventures-with-adverbials-part-2/3521224.html)

Unless anyone has any corrections to make, this seems to me the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

*It was a long time comming* is not an idiom and there are plenty of examples that have *a long time* as an adjunct that comes between a form of *be* and the gerund-participle (-ing form)

A sample from the Corpus of Historical American English

> Pretty Betsy Canning **was a long time finding** out that Husband Alec
>   was not the man she thought she married. (Time Magazine: 1937/04/05)
>
> Preach **was a long time recovering** from this 1946 injury. (Saturday
>   Evening Post: 2/3/1951, Vol. 223 Issue 32, p30-67, 5p)
>
> She **was a long time milking** the cows; her hands were so tired she
>   had often to stop and rest them, while the tears fell unheeded into
>   the pail. (Other Main-Travelled Roads; Garland, Hamlin, 1860-1940)
>
> Brin **was a long time responding**. (Wishsong of Shannara , Terry
>   Brooks, 1985)
>
> Ella **was a long time coaxing** Rancie to be friends, because the
>   child was wild and shy. (Harpers Magazine (1935-04) pages: 525-532)

We understand most of these either as *late* or *for a long time*.

Similar constructions with noun phrases as adjuncts of duration exist as well:

> They **were five days finding** parts to rebuild the engine. (The Hotel
>   New Hampshire, John Irving, 1981)
>
> An English family by the name of Bancroft, who had **been seven weeks
>   crossing** the ocean in a sailing-vessel, had located and started a
>   real greenhouse. (Song of Years , Bess Streeter Aldrich, 1939)
>
> Do not let us assume that this is the bill for a long, active
>   operation; we **were two days fighting** and previously we had **been
>   one week bombing** (House of Commons,
>   army_supplementary_estimate_1956)

Although it may not be common, this construction has been in use for some time.